# Equating coefficients explanation for trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry

Equating coefficients for the trigonometric identities does not make sense for me and I will explain why:

If I use the example

Write $5\cos x - 3 \sin x$ in the form $k\sin(x - \alpha)$, where $0 \le \alpha \le 360$.

$=5\cos x - 3\sin x = k\sin(x - \alpha)$

$= k(\sin x\cos \alpha - \cos x\sin \alpha)$

$= k\cos\alpha\sin x - k \sin\alpha\cos x$ -- no idea why x and $\alpha$ switch here

$= k \cos \alpha = -3$

I have no idea where $k\cos\alpha = -3$ comes from when in the previous expression, $k\cos\alpha$ is on the left of the minus sign so surely it should be $k\cos\alpha = 5$

Then we have

$= k \sin \alpha = -5$

Same as above, $k \sin \alpha$ is on the right hand side of the minus so I have no idea why it is now assigned to -5.

It is like I have to do the opposite to get the actual value.  Really confused.

Comment: I also do not understand where $kcos\alpha=-3$ comes from. I think this step is incorrect.

Comment: I'm copying it verbatim.  I've also seen this in more than one place

Comment: $k\cos \alpha$ is the coefficient of $\sin x$, so is $-3$.

Comment: Alright, yes that makes sense now. But I am confused as to what the purpose is of all this.

Comment: @peterwhy how do I match $k\cos \alpha$ to the original expression?  So the order of $k\cos \alpha\sin x - k\sin \alpha\cos x$ has nothing to do with the order of $5\cos x - 3 \sin x$?  Is this my confusion, I am looking at $5\cos x - 3 \sin x$ and expecting both sides of the minus sign to be the same as $k\cos \alpha\sin x - k\sin \alpha\cos x$

Comment: But by commutativity $5\cos x - 3 \sin x = -3 \sin x + 5\cos x$.

Comment: what does commutativity mean in this context

Comment: That means you can swap between $a+b$ and $b+a$.

Comment: Ok but I yes but how is $k\cos \alpha = -3$, I don't seem to be getting any closer when it makes more sense to me for $k\cos \alpha = 5$

Comment: But this is by directly comparing the coefficients of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$: $$\underline5\color{red}{\cos x} +\underline{(-3)}\color{blue}{\sin x} \equiv \underline{k\cos\alpha}\color{blue}{\sin x} +\underline{(- k\sin\alpha)}\color{red}{\cos x}$$

Comment: thank you for your patience and help

Comment: So do these answer your question? Or do I still not understand where the confusion is?

Comment: @peterwhy yes, thank you so much, I can see that $k\cos \alpha$ is the coefficient of $\sin x$ and $k\sin \alpha$ is the coefficient of $\cos x$

Comment: The colour highlighting is what made the penny drop.  I can progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are linearly independent -- if you are given 
$$A\sin x + B\cos x \equiv 0$$
then both $A=B=0$.

---

Proof: If given $A\sin x + B\cos x \equiv 0$, then
$$\begin{align*}
A\sin x + B\cos x &\equiv 0\\
A\sin0^\circ + B\cos 0^\circ &= 0 &\iff&&B = 0\\
A\sin 90^\circ + B\cos 90^\circ &= 0 &\iff &&A=0
\end{align*}$$

---

So you have made to the point that

$$\begin{align*}
5\cos x -3\sin x &\equiv k\cos\alpha\sin x - k\sin\alpha\cos x\\
5\cos x+k\sin\alpha\cos x -3\sin x-k\cos\alpha\sin x &\equiv 0\\
(5+ k\sin\alpha)\cos x + (-3-k\cos\alpha)\sin x &\equiv 0
\end{align*}$$

From the result above,
$$\begin{align*}
5+k\sin\alpha &= 0&\iff&&-k\sin\alpha &= 5\\
-3-k\cos\alpha &= 0 &\iff&&k\cos\alpha &= -3
\end{align*}$$
which is the result of directly matching the coefficients of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$.

Comment: I am sorry but that explanation does not mean anything to me

Comment: I'm just wondering whether $5+k\sin \alpha$ has to equal $0$ as the equation would stand true even when $5+k\sin\alpha$ does not equal $0$ if $\cos x = 0$. The same goes for $(-3-k\cos\alpha)\sin x$

Comment: @Mathsexplorer the important bit here is that $\cos x$ does *not* always $= 0$ (i.e. for some $x$, $\cos x \ne 0$). Then from the general identity,

$$5\cos x -  3 \sin x \equiv k \cos \alpha \sin x - k \sin \alpha \cos x$$

By choosing a specific $x$ so that $\cos x \ne 0$ and $\sin x = 0$ (for example $x = 0^\circ$), the equality at that $x$ becomes


$$\begin{align*}
5\cos 0 - 3 \cdot 0 &= k \cos \alpha \cdot 0 - k \sin \alpha \cos 0\\
5 \cos 0 &= -k\sin \alpha \cos 0\\
5 &= -k\sin \alpha
\end{align*}$$